# C# Using XmlSerializer to create array of elements with attributes from simple string array

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, serialization

I have a simple class which I'd want to serialize using XmlSerializer:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class SomeClass
{
    [XmlArray("Items")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Item")]
    public string[] itemsArray { get; set; }
}
```

which produces XML like this:

```
<root>
    <Items>
      <Item>someText1</Item>
      <Item>someText2</Item>
      <Item>someText3</Item>
    </Items>
</root>
```

What I'd want to have is an array of elements with attributes:

```
<root>
    <Items>
      <Item someAttribute="someText1" />
      <Item someAttribute="someText2" />
      <Item someAttribute="someText3" />
    </Items>
</root>
```

How to do that without creating new class with property decorated as XmlAttribute?

EDIT: From what I've found here 
[XmlSerializer: serializing a class property as an attribute of a custom subelement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159218/xmlserializer-serializing-a-class-property-as-an-attribute-of-a-custom-subeleme) 
it seems it's not possible. Could anyone confirm?

Comment: Eliminate XmlArray and XmlArrayItem and replace with XmlElement.  You don't need both tags Items and Item.  Only one is necessary.  If you have both Items and Item then you need another class.

Comment: @jdweng I thought so. Thanks.